# Is it possible to create an car object in sfml that consists of a parallelogram, a rectangle, and two wheels?

Tags: sfml

I created a car in c++ and sfml:

And here is how:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1500, 600), "SFML Window", Style::Default);

window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

cout << "haha" << endl;

VertexArray curve(LinesStrip);

for (int x = 0; x <= 1500; x+=50)
{
    curve.append(Vertex(Vector2f(x, 300 - cos(x)*200)));
}


ConvexShape carRoof;
RectangleShape carBody;
CircleShape backWheel, frontWheel;

carRoof.setPointCount(4);
carRoof.setOutlineThickness(4);
carRoof.setPoint(0, Vector2f(38, 55));
carRoof.setPoint(1, Vector2f(50, 45));
carRoof.setPoint(2, Vector2f(80, 45));
carRoof.setPoint(3, Vector2f(92, 55));
carRoof.setOrigin(0, 0);
carRoof.setFillColor(Color::Black);
carRoof.setPosition(0, -4.0f);

carBody.setOutlineThickness(4);
carBody.setSize(Vector2f(90, 14));
carBody.setPosition(20, 58.5);
carBody.setFillColor(Color::Black);

backWheel.setRadius(8);
backWheel.setPointCount(100);
backWheel.setPosition(35, 75);
backWheel.setOrigin(4, 4);
backWheel.setOutlineThickness(4);
backWheel.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);

frontWheel.setRadius(8);
frontWheel.setPointCount(100);
frontWheel.setPosition(80, 75);
frontWheel.setOrigin(4, 4);
frontWheel.setOutlineThickness(4);
frontWheel.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);


Event event;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
        {
            window.close();
        }
    }

    window.clear();

    window.draw(curve);
    
    window.draw(carRoof);
    window.draw(carBody);
    window.draw(backWheel);
    window.draw(frontWheel);
    
    window.display();

}
return 0;
```

}

I am wondering how can I create a class Car such that these 4 object are combined into one, so that it can have even it's own move function like the individual shapes, and also it should be drawable. I have spent a few days trying to tackle this out but to no avail.

Comment: Could you post the original code than a screen shot ?

Comment: I posted the original code Belle

Comment: Please can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Car` class that inherits `sf::Drawable` and overloads the `draw()` function. Then you can add your custom functions like `move()` and anything that you could expect from a car. This way you can instantiate as many `Car`s as you want and draw them like you would with any other SFML shape.
Here's the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) for `sf::Drawable`.